# features for same content type but different structure collide in multi site

Tags: 7, features, multi-sites

I have a multi site and one content type has different fields in it than the same content type in a different site.

When I make a feature for this content type, they conflict with each other even though I have not enabled one of them in the other multi site.

Is it possible to have different features that don't conflict within a multi site if content type is the same but with different fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diana,

Why not move the features into their specific site directories?
Then they dont 'see' each other in the other sites.

For example:

Feature 1 is located in sites/site1/modules/feature1

Feature 2 is located in sites/site2/modules/feature2

Then they are "unaware" of each other.

Would this work?